# How to avoid table for each user

Tags: mysql, excel, design-patterns, database-design

I have a rather special use case in front of me. There is to be an excel file with around a thousand entries (rows), each row represents something that the USER should pass judgment on.

Now, the entries are the same for everyone. The data that should be collected is
a) how many users like any given entry
b) what entries does any given user like

Since part of the app is already running and we have user accounts,
I thought of creating a table for each user (!) containing said excel information, adding a row for collecting the votes. I would create those tables by iteratin through the user list and creating tables like "userid_excelentries".

I don't think that's elegant. I would prefer to store the excel information only once in a table and only save the users' votes in the table "user".

**The app is meant to display a table created form the excel table (I have the grid already done) and a row next to it with checkboxes. How do I structure this ? Temporary tables ? How do I store the information what each user has selected in the "user" table, since I don't know how many selections will be made a-priori ?**

I had this crazy idea of actually handling the xls object through javascript, serializing it into a hash and storing that hash into a field in each user's row...but I have no clue if this is sane :o

---

We're facing a user count of exactly 272 - this is why I considered doing the "one table for each user" approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 3 tables in your DB

```
users table
-----------
id
name
...


entries table
-------------
id
name
...


user_entries table
------------------
user_id
entry_id
user_response
```

To get all entries a certain user (i.e. `Tom`) likes you can do

```
select e.name
from entries e
join user_entries ue on ue.entry_id = e.id
join users u on ue.user_id = u.id
where u.name = 'tom'
and ue.user_response = 'like'
```

And to get the count of likes for each entry you can do

```
select e.name, count(ue.user_id) as likes
from entries e
join user_entries ue on ue.entry_id = e.id
where ue.user_response = 'like'
group by e.id, e.name
```

Comment: user_id and entry_id would be foreign keys in the user_entries table ?
<br>
How would the query look like tha culls the info a) and b) ? (see OP)

Comment: I haven't implemented this yet but I marked your answer since it is clear to me what I need to do. That is a great answer.